# Internet Explorer and Angular JS

Tags: internet-explorer, angularjs

Currently having a problem in regards to Internet Explorer and angular js.

The html, as shown below, is rendering fine in Chrome and Firefox, however, anything in the ng-view tags does not render at all in IE.

```
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org">
<html lang="en" ng-app="poc">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>poc</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/filters.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>
<script src="cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-view>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The partial that I am trying to inject into this is shown below:

```
<section>
<h1>Proof of Concept</h1>
<ul>
<li><a href="#/phonegap">Try Phonegap Features</a></li>
<li><a href="#/observations">Test Websocket Requests</a></li>
<li><a href="#/persondetails">Test Person Details Requests</a></li>
</ul>
<section>
```

The code below shows the routing implementation we are using:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('poc', ['pocFilters', 'pocServices']).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider.
    when('/poc', {templateUrl: 'partials/poc.html',   controller: PocCtrl}).

    when('/observations', {templateUrl: 'partials/observations.html', 
    controller: ObservationsCtrl}).

    when('/phonegap', {templateUrl: 'partials/phonegap.html',
    controller: PhonegapCtrl}).

    when('/persondetails', {templateUrl: 'partials/persondetails.html',
    controller: PersondetailsCtrl}).

    otherwise({redirectTo: '/poc'});
}]);
```

Anyone have any ideas as to what could be causing the problem in IE?

Thanks,

Patrick

Comment: Have you tried just having all the HTML in one file without going through angular? This will tell you if it's an IE issue or an angular issue.

Comment: Hi dnc253, yes I have tried doing so and it renders fine. It works fine using angular in both Chrome and Firefox so it's perhaps some sort of bug or weird quirk using IE with angular.

Answer (score 12):

First you should look at angularjs doc on [IE](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie). I wrote an IE Shiv for [angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.com/) which frees you from doing this and when you create element style directives (which ng-view, ng-include etc are), you can instruct shiv of which of your angular modules have these directives.

Answer (score 3):

Add `id="ng-app"` to the tag in which you are using **ng-app** directive. In your case the tag is `<html>`. Hence your html tag should look like the following, in order to make the app rendered in IE.

`<html lang="en" ng-app="poc" id="ng-app">`

instead of

`<html lang="en" ng-app="poc">`

Answer (score 1):

Angular 1.2 **RC1** does not play well with **IE 11**: it has a CORS issue when routing. The result is that views are not rendered (as their content is not fetched)

If you suspect this is the issue - open the console (F12). You can see the exception there.

This was resolved in Angular 1.2 **RC3**.

Comment: Great...I had a 1.2.0 version... switched to 1.2.32 solved the issue... thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 elements need a shim (specifically the section tag), you have two html tags when you need just one, you should really have a doctype declared, and you also need to add id="ng-app" to the html tag for IE7 to work.

To shim elements, create a script (file or just a tag) with a `document.createElement();` statement for each element - in your case `document.createElement('section')`.

That should set you right.

Comment: Also, you should close the section tag rather than opening another `</section>`